# SQL trigger - Always update or conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

In my scenario a single password in table B needs to be updated when this password changes in table A. I've been given a trigger which does this, but the trigger always updates the value, even when the password in table A isn't modified, but one of the other fields is modified.
This seems like overkill to me, because the trigger can be modified to update only when specifically the password field is modified.

Is the provided solution decent, or would it be better (performance wise mainly) to change the trigger and add a condition on which to actually modify the row. I can imagine the cost of conditionally updating being greater than blindly changing the value every time.

Current code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UserSync]
ON [dbo].[Import]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(128)
  DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(128)

  SELECT @UserName=Username
  ,      @Password=Password
  FROM   INSERTED

  UPDATE UserLogin
  SET Password = @Password
  WHERE Name = @UserName
END
```

Comment: Tag dbms to get better attention. (That code isn't ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @UserName=Username, @Password=Password FROM   INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get *one arbitrary row* and you'll ignore all others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better was to write this, to a) allow for updates of multiple rows as per @marc_s and b) only update where it has changed, is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UserSync]
ON [dbo].[Import]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE UserLogin
  SET Password = i.password
  from UserLogon u
  inner join inserted i on i.Name = u.Name
  inner join deleted d on d.Name = i.Name
  WHERE i.password <> u.password
END
```

So, for each user in the transaction the old (deleted) and the new (inserted) are matched against the underlying table (UserLogon). Where the new password is different to the old, the underlying table is updated.

Comment: Do you know about the IF (UPDATE (password)) construction? Or is this preferred?

Comment: Given that this is a single statement set operation, and anything involving code is not, I'd always go with the single statement set operation.